# Classic ASP get textbox value - using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to upload a file to my server.  The file is uploading but I would like to get the value that is in the File1 textbox.  I do NOT want the path, I want just the filename that I'm saving.

```
<html>
    <head>
     <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form name="uploadr" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File 1 : <input name="File1" type="file"/><br/><br/>
                 <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Upload files &gt;&gt;" /><br/>
                 <input name="hiddenVal" type="hidden" value="testVal" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following VBScript:

```
<% 
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 2000
    Form.SizeLimit = &H100000

    If Form.State = 0 Then 'Completed
        Form.Files.Save DestinationPath 
        response.write "<br><Font Color=green>File  (" & Form.TotalBytes \1024 & "kB) was saved to " & DestinationPath & " folder.</Font>"
        response.write(document.uploadr.hiddenVal.value())
    ElseIf Form.State > 10 then
      Const fsSizeLimit = &HD
      Select case Form.State
            case fsSizeLimit: response.write  "<br><Font Color=red>Source form size (" & Form.TotalBytes & "B) exceeds form limit (" & Form.SizeLimit & "B)</Font><br>"
            case else response.write "<br><Font Color=red>Some form error.</Font><br>"
      end Select
    End If'Form.State = 0 then

%>
```

When it gets to the `response.write(document.uploadr.hiddenVal.value())` it says 'Document' variable undefined.

What do I need to do to get the value of the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`response.write(UploadFormRequest("hiddenVal"))`